# Can I buy non-essential, non-magical items in League play at my own leisure?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, dnd-adventurers-league

I played my first public 5e Adventurers League session. I got gold now and I want to buy helpful items and tools: mainly things like a component pouch, bull’s-eye lantern, candles, caltrops, etc. Also possibly a mount and saddlebags for extra weight as I'm trying to honor all the rules for AL.

I know you can't buy magical or homebrew items. How does gold spending work with modular campaigns and normal adventuring gear?